# Why is my model exported from Blender vanishing when using it in UE4 mobile?

Tags: blender, unreal-4

My 3D models and animation vanishes when I preview it using the mobile view port. However they work just fine for the desktop viewport.

I usually model the characters using MakeHuman and import them into Blender. In Blender I animate them and then I import the model/animation into UE4. The problem is that my model/animation works when I preview it using the shader meant for desktop & consoles. When I preview my animation using the openGLES2 shader, my model vanishes. Anything I import form belnder vanishes when I view it in a mobile viewport. I cant figure out why this is so? Have any of you experienced this before ? Can you guys let me know how I can correct this issue?

Also, if I upload the models from MakeHuman into UE directly, I can upload the files properly in UE. But, when I try the workflow MakeHuman -> Blender -> UE with not much modifications to the models in Blender, the models are not visible in the openGLES2 shader. I am not sure why this is happening in Blender and why the models coming out if it is affected.

Any help would be appreciated.